# How to fix the error of unknown mutation type in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have googled this error however the answers I get, didn't help me. I am trying to make a like-dislike count with using Vuex. I am using jsonplaceholder for data. Here I take my data and setting a like attribute for all the objects.

```js
actions: {
async fetchPhotos({commit}) {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
      commit('setPhotos', response.data.splice(0,100))
    },
}

mutations: {
setPhotos: (state, photos) => {
      (state.albumList = photos);
      state.albumList.forEach(element => element.likes = 0)}
}
```

After in my dom I want to use one button for dislike and other for like. I want to display the like counter when I click the buttons.

```html
<div v-for="photos in allPhotos" :key="photos.id">
        <div class="card" @click="detail(photos)"><img :src="photos.thumbnailUrl" alt=""></div>
        <div class="likes">
          <div class="myButton" ><button class="red" @click="minus(photos.id)"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></div>
          <div>{{photos.likes}}</div>
          <div class="myButton "><button class="green" @click="plus(photos.id)"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

So I added minus mutations in my store and in my script.

```
methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['minus']),
```

```
state: {
    albumList : [],
  },

mutations: {
    minus: (state, id) => {
      state.albumList[id-1].likes--
   },
```

After all this, I am having an error:

> [vuex] unknown mutation type: minus.

I can't see what I am doing wrong here.

PS:I also trimmed the code for it to be clearer.

Comment: what about `@click="$store.commit('minus',photos.id)"`?

Comment: same error as it was before

Comment: please share your `main.js` and the store code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working example. Also double check your vuex store configuration/registration.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        items: [
            {
                title: "item1",
                likes: 10
            },
            {
                title: "item2",
                likes: 24
            }
        ]
    },
    actions: {
        like({ commit }, id) {
            commit("LIKE_ITEM", id);
        },
        dislike({ commit }, id) {
            commit("DISLIKE_ITEM", id);
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        LIKE_ITEM(state, id) {
            state.items[id].likes++;
        },
        DISLIKE_ITEM(state, id) {
            state.items[id].likes--;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        items(state) {
            return state.items;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store,
    computed: {
        items() {
            return this.$store.getters.items;
        }
    },
    data: () => {
        return {};
    },
    methods: {
        like(id) {
            this.$store.dispatch("like", id);
        },
        dislike(id) {
            this.$store.dispatch("dislike", id);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
    <div v-for='(item, i) in items' :key="i">
        {{item.title }}: {{item.likes}} likes
        <button @click='like(i)'>Like +</button> <button @click='dislike(i)'>Dislike -</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

I have had this for about 12 hours now. Using vuex 4.0.1.
After a lot of googling, I have come to the following conclusion about this issue above for some of the most common causes:

##### Common issues why this may happen

1. Not sure about this but was one of the suggestions, versions (this happened somewhere between versions 2 around there). I don't think this is no longer an issue,
2. Second and most important, naming:

- if using namespaced modules ensure you prefix the module e.g. `this.$store.commit('moduleName/myMutation');`
- Naming your `mutations`, `actions` within your modules. Just confirm and ensure you've got the correct spelling
- For namespaced modules, ensure you add `namespaced: true` within it.

> actually the later was my problem after setting mine to `namespace: true` instead of `namespaced: true`

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. The checklist is very useful and helped me figure out my problem.